# if grep statement never returning true, always returns 'no such file or directory'

Tags: bash, grep

I have been tasked with writing a method that counts the number of Red Ford Fiestas in a list of cars, then outputs that number to a `.txt` file, specifically without using the `-c` option in grep

```
numberCars=0
while read car
do
    echo $car
    if grep -E Ford\:Fiesta.*Red $car; then
        echo "-------DONE------"
        (($numberCars++))
    fi
done < $userInput
echo $numberCars > output/Fiesta_Red.txt
```

The first `echo $car` works, so I know the while loop is working correctly. However, each `if grep` returns the details of the car followed by "`No such file or directory`". I have tested, each `if` is returning false, regardless of whether the pattern I'm searching for exists or not

For reference, this is an example of how the `carslist.txt` is formatted:

```
Peugeot:206:2000:Black:1
Ford:Fiesta:2000:Red:2
```

Comment: You know that `grep` takes a filename, right?

Comment: That's what $userInput is, it's the filename specified by the user

Comment: You're not passing `$userInput` to `grep`.

Comment: I meant $car.
It should read the specific details of the car (i.e. Ford:Focus:2000:Red:2) and grep that

Comment: That's not what grep does. Read my first comment again.

Comment: Okay then, how would I fix that?
I want a statement that returns true if the pattern exists for each line of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution to test the pattern

```
[[ $car =~ Ford\:Fiesta.*Red ]] && echo "-------DONE------" && (($numberCars++))
```